# How to improve speed of fetching records?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using a Firebird 2.5 and have IBExpert to manage the database.

I have a stored procedure where the performance on execute is ok (see image of performance), but the fetch records time is slow.

The total results are approx 6000 rows, but takes approx 1 sec to retrieve 500 rows at a time when fetching all.

This is the analysis of the query time:
[image]

This is the stored procedure:

```sql
begin
  /* Get the selected Account Type ID and CurrentMonth only if the Account had started then */
  for select id, acc_number, acc_name, currentmonth, account_type_style_table_id, job_nos
  from accounts_table
  where (account_type_table_id = :ip_account_type_table_id) and
        cast( 01 || '.' || actual_month_started || '.' || actual_year_started as DATE) <= :ip_entering_month_year_as_date
  order by acc_number_text, acc_number_no
  into :v_account_table_id, :v_account_number, :v_account_name, :v_current_month, :op_acc_type_style_table_id, :op_job_nos do
  begin
    v_temp_bf_debit = 0;
    v_temp_bf_credit = 0;

    /* Get the Brought Forward Amounts from the Monthly Summary. The amounts are put into our Temporary variables so we can check if we need this Account */
    select sum(accmst.debit_amount), sum(accmst.credit_amount)
    from accounts_table acct inner join account_mthly_sum_totals_table accmst on (acct.id = accmst.account_table_id)
    where (accmst.entering_month_year_as_date < :ip_entering_month_year_as_date) and (acct.id = :v_account_table_id)
    group by acct.id, acct.acc_name, acct.acc_number
    into :v_temp_bf_debit, :v_temp_bf_credit;

    /* Just set this to zero if a null value has been returned. We may have search for the very first month which there wont be any Brought Forward amounts */
    if (v_temp_bf_debit is null) then
    begin
      v_temp_bf_debit = 0;
    end
    /* Just set this to zero if a null value has been returned. We may have search for the very first month which there wont be any Brought Forward amounts */
    if (v_temp_bf_credit is null) then
    begin
      v_temp_bf_credit = 0;
    end

    /* As we already have the Brought Forward Amounts we can set the variables here. No need to get again */
    op_account_table_id = v_account_table_id;
    op_account_number = v_account_number;
    op_account_name = v_account_name;
    op_description = :ip_broughtforward_str;
    op_debit = v_temp_bf_debit;
    op_credit = v_temp_bf_credit;
    op_batch_date = null;
    op_reference = '';
    suspend;

    /* Get the selected month only from the Batch */
    for select bit.account_name, bit.account_number, biht.batch_date_datetime, bit.reference, bit.description, bit.debit_amount, bit.credit_amount,
               biht.batch_type, biht.batch_type_extra
    from batch_input_table bit inner join batch_input_hdr_table biht on (bit.batch_input_hdr_table_id = biht.id)
    where (bit.account_id = :v_account_table_id) and
          (biht.entering_month_year_as_date = :ip_entering_month_year_as_date)
    order by biht.datetime_created, bit.id
    into :op_account_name, :op_account_number, :op_batch_date, :op_reference, :op_description, :op_debit, :op_credit, :op_batch_type, :op_batch_type_extra do
    begin
      suspend;
    end

    /* Get the Aged Report Values Now */
    v_m = 1;

    /* Start a loop for the number of months to get  */
    while (v_m <= :ip_no_of_months) do
    begin
      /* Current Month Year */
      if (v_m = 1) then
      begin
        select the_total
        from aged_report_month_table
        where (account_table_id = :v_account_table_id)  and
              (entering_month_year_as_date = :ip_entering_month_year_as_date)
        into :op_debit;
        op_account_table_id = v_account_table_id;
        op_account_number = v_account_number;
        op_account_name = v_account_name;
        op_description = ip_first_month_str;
        op_batch_date = null;
        op_reference = '';
        op_credit = 0;
        op_job_nos = '';
        suspend;
      end
      else
      begin
        /* Previous Month Year */
        if (v_m = 2) then
        begin
          v_temp_date = DateAdd(month, -1, ip_entering_month_year_as_date);

          select the_total
          from aged_report_month_table
          where (account_table_id = :v_account_table_id) and
                (entering_month_year_as_date = :v_temp_date)
          into :op_debit;
          op_account_table_id = v_account_table_id;
          op_account_number = v_account_number;
          op_account_name = v_account_name;
          op_description = ip_second_month_str;
          op_batch_date = null;
          op_reference = '';
          op_credit = 0;
          op_job_nos = '';
          suspend;
        end
        else
        begin
          /* Two Months ago */
          if (v_m = 3) then
          begin
            v_temp_date = DateAdd(month, -2, ip_entering_month_year_as_date);

            select the_total
            from aged_report_month_table
            where (account_table_id = :v_account_table_id) and
                  (entering_month_year_as_date = :v_temp_date)
            into :op_debit;
            op_account_table_id = v_account_table_id;
            op_account_number = v_account_number;
            op_account_name = v_account_name;
            op_description = ip_third_month_str;
            op_batch_date = null;
            op_reference = '';
            op_credit = 0;
            op_job_nos = '';
            suspend;
          end
        end
      end

      /* Last Month will get the Month and all before */
      if (v_m = :ip_no_of_months) then
      begin
        v_temp_date = DateAdd(month, -:ip_no_of_months, ip_entering_month_year_as_date);

        select Sum(armt.the_total)
        from aged_report_month_table armt inner join accounts_table acct on (armt.account_table_id = acct.id)
        where ((acct.id = :v_account_table_id) and (acct.account_type_table_id = :ip_account_type_table_id) and
               (armt.entering_month_year_as_date <= :v_temp_date))
        into :op_debit;
        op_account_table_id = v_account_table_id;
        op_account_number = v_account_number;
        op_account_name = v_account_name;
        op_description = ip_fourth_month_str;
        op_batch_date = null;
        op_reference = '';
        op_credit = 0;
        op_job_nos = '';
        suspend;
      end

      v_m = v_m + 1;
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas on what is slowing the fetching of records and how can I improve it?

Comment: The execution itself of the stored procedure is quick because that hardly does anything. The actual work of a stored procedure happens when records are fetched. The main problem with your code is that it exhibits the dreaded N+1 query problem (actually even worse than that, because you have a lot of loops in loops that fire additional queries). And if you don't have proper indexes, performance will suffer even more.

Comment: In any case, this isn't something that can be addressed easily without a lot more details about the DDL of the tables and indexes, and even then it is a lot of code to go over, I'm not sure you'll get a quick answer (if any) about this here.

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel. Thanks for taking the time to reply.   

Is then the fetch part of the stored procedure performed based on what the client has requested in total results? My IBexpert executes the above store procedure within a second with 42 results(aprox). If I then goto the last results row then it takes approx 1 second per 500 results to collect.  

There are no "None Index Reads".  

Is my problem a case of N+1 queries and or I need to add some single/double index's(I appreciate you might not be able to answer this without the complete picture)?

Comment: @Yuppski it is event in PSQL documentation... The procedure executes up to the `suspend` command, when it expected to set output row in the parameters, then it locks and waits for the client application to fetch that row, unlocking the procedure. Then it runs until next `suspend` command and so it keeps repeating itself.

Comment: Frankly, getting totalled history of looong operations is complex task itself. Complexity would be either in shoveling gigabytes of raw data, or in designing nested half-baked 
cached totals tables (like, totals per-week, then totals per-year, then totals-per-century on time scale, and then same cascaded totalling might be devised for customers) and then coprrectly utilizing/flushing those cache tables.

Comment: You might try to ease the problem by enlarging RAM cache for Firebird (see articles and some "try maybe would work" conf-files on ib-aid.com) however it would only be a question of time until accumulated data would catch up and overwhelm this quantitaive easying

Comment: @ Arioch. Thanks for the information.